# Concatenate columns for rows containing floats, integers and strings

Tags: python

I have a 10x10 matrix and I would like to obtain a 10x1 matrix. So for each row, I would like to concatenate all columns, and it should not matter if a column contains a float or integer that needs to be concatenated with a string

I would basically like to achieve the following:

```
' '.join([table[1][2],table[1][3],table[1][4]])
```

And I tried to do it with the following for loop:

```
joinit = []
for r in xrange(0,len(table)): 
    joinit[c][r] = ' '.join([table[c][r],table[c][r+1]])
```

However, it gives me errors like `'list index out of range'`

The data would look like follows:

```
0      1      2      3      4      5        6
Hello  I      would  like   5      cups
We     do     not    have   that   0.05     sir
```

With uneven number of columns for each row that are filled.

Comment: An example would help clarify what you want...

Comment: Please post your code and tell us where you got stuck. You should also visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: added an example as requested :)

Comment: You get an error because `joinit` is an empty list, it has no `c`

Comment: t.m. adam, I did not post the snippet that actually fills the joinit table as it was irrelevant for the question, and I did not want to bother people with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this function.  It looks up the largest column length and sets that to the `rjust`.

```
table = [
    [1,2,3,"testing",5],
    [1,"bob",3,4,5],
    [1,2,3,4,5]
]

def makeTable(table):
    getRJust = max(max(len(str(j)) for j in i) for i in table)
    for i in table:
        print(", ".join([str(l).rjust(getRJust) for l in i]))

makeTable(table)
```

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks !